# Set props value on vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've write a vue component that is supposed to receive the "uploadedFile" prop, but its not working.
I'm just receiving the correct information on the $attrs:

[image]

My component:

```js
Vue.component('table-file', {
props: ['files'],
template: '<div class="row"><table class= "table table-sm table-hover"><thead><tr><th scope="col" style="text-align: center">FILE NAME</th><th scope="col" style="text-align: center; width: 20%;" colspan="2">OPTIONS</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr v-for="(file, index) in files" :key="index" style="text-align: center;"><td scope="row" style="font-size: medium !important">{{file.FileName}}</td><td><Button class="btn btn-info btn-raised" v-on:click="downloadFile(file.ID)" style="margin: 0">Download</Button></td><td>\<Button class="btn btn-info btn-raised" v-on:click="deleteFile(file.ID)" style="margin: 0; background-color: red">Delete</Button></td></tr></tbody ></table ></div >'
})
```

```html
<table-file :files="uploadedFile"></table-file>
```

Can anyone helps me?

Comment: can you share parent component code

Answer (score 2):

Your file is called `uploadedfile` and not `uploadedFile`

Answer (score 0):

Letter case is important in JavaScript. Rename uploadedFile -> uploadedfile.

```js
Vue.component('table-file', {
props: ['files'],
template: '<div class="row"><table class= "table table-sm table-hover"><thead><tr><th scope="col" style="text-align: center">FILE NAME</th><th scope="col" style="text-align: center; width: 20%;" colspan="2">OPTIONS</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr v-for="(file, index) in files" :key="index" style="text-align: center;"><td scope="row" style="font-size: medium !important">{{file.FileName}}</td><td><Button class="btn btn-info btn-raised" v-on:click="downloadFile(file.ID)" style="margin: 0">Download</Button></td><td>\<Button class="btn btn-info btn-raised" v-on:click="deleteFile(file.ID)" style="margin: 0; background-color: red">Delete</Button></td></tr></tbody ></table ></div >'
})
```

```html
<table-file :files="uploadedfile"></table-file> // case is important, you have lowercase var.
```